# Cannot restart tmux session - Cannot unlink tmux socket file

Tags: tmux, socket

I am using **tmux** to create a **shared session** in /tmp called tekkit.

All works fine, with one major exception.
**When the tmux session is closed, the /tmp/tekkit socket file remains in place.** This is a big issue, as now **nobody, besides the owner of that socket file can start this session again**

Running the command: `tmux -S /tmp/tekkit new -d sh TekkitLaunch.sh`

Presents all other users with: `error connecting to /tmp/tekkit (Operation not permitted)`

**All users are part of the same group, and have full rwx permissions on the socket file.**

Normally, I’d unlink the socket file after closing the session, however that also doesn’t work, as **only the file owner can unlink it**. All other users, even tho they have the necessary permissions to do so, cannot unlink it and are presented with this error: `unlink: cannot unlink '/tmp/tekkit': Operation not permitted`

*I am unlinking the file like so: `unlink /tmp/tekkit`*

**My questions are:**

What am I doing wrong and how do I either:

**A)**  Let the socket file stay as it is but be able to start a new session with another user after the first session is closed.

**B)**  Unlink the socket file with other users than the file owner.

**Both solutions need to work without super-user access!**

Thank You for Your help.

Answer (score 0):

Symlinks in `/tmp` are only follow-able by the symlink owner

[Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#Symlink_restrictions)

> In Ubuntu 10.10 and later, symlinks in world-writable sticky directories (e.g. /tmp) cannot be followed **if the follower and directory owner do not match the symlink owner.**

---

> Both solutions need to work without super-user access!

As far as I know, this is impossible.

The only way to disable this security feature is to disable `protected_symlinks` (which has security implications, so `root` is necessary)

Either by

```
sysctl -w fs.protected_symlinks=0
```

Or by adding `fs.protected_symlinks=0` to either a file in `/etc/sysctl.d` or editing directly `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: The file involved is a socket file, not a symlink. This is entirely because `/tmp` has a sticky bit enabled that prevents users other than the owner from deleting the file.